# Automatic start of dask distributed scheduler and workers on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-2.7, systemd, ubuntu-16.04, dask

I am considering different methods to automatically start and control dask distributed scheduler and workers on Ubuntu 16.04.

Currently I think that the most relevant option is to use systemd daemon. This requires creation and installation of [unit files](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html).

Systemd requires that a unit file should have a command line to stop the service, set in `ExecStop`.

Command to reload configuration would also be useful, however, I'm not sure, how to make Python to reimport modules and if it is more simple than just restart the process.

Looks like currently it is not possible to stop scheduler/workers by running `dask-scheduler` or `dask-worker` command, isn't it? I haven't found any relevant command line switches.

Another option would be to create PID file and use standard `kill` command, however, Dask distributed doesn't seem to create PID files. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send an interrupt signal (such as occurs when you Ctrl-C) to the `dask-worker` or `dask-scheduler` process they will intercept it and shutdown cleanly.

We don't currently write PID files but this would be easy to do.  I recommend that you [open an issue](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/new) if this is something that you think should be included in the project.  Same with creating proper start/stop commands common in other services.

Comment: Yes, but one needs a process ID to send an interrupt signal, and finding it is sometimes not easy.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've come to setting `ExecStop=/bin/true`. Systemd still successfully stops and restarts the services.

[Current systemd manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) says that `ExecStop` is optional.